# How to query field from related record in sfdcDigest transformation in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: relationships, einstein-analytics

As title says,Is it possible to get field from a related record in `sfdcDigest` transformation in Einstein Analytics?

I have looked at [sfdcDigest transformation documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_salesforce_extract_transformation.htm&type=5) and don't see anything about it.

Created JSON as below to query Account name from Contact but it is failing.

```
  "Extract_Contacts": {
    "action": "sfdcDigest",
    "parameters": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Account.Name"
        }
      ],
      "object": "Contact"
    }
  }
```

Error:

[image]

This is what I am doing for now: Extract Account records and Contact records separately and then do [update transformation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_update_transformation.htm&type=5) to join the records. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EA you first need to extract the data (using SFDCDigest Transformation) from each Object and then Join them (Using Augment Transformation).

In your case
1. extract Contact
2. extract Account
3. augment Contact & Account using AccountID from Contact and ID from Account as left and right key. Now Select Name from Extract Account Node in Right Select Fields.

Left Node : Extract Contact
Right Node : Extract Account
Left Key  : AccountId
Right Key : Key
Right Selected Fields : ["Name"]
Relationship Name: "Account"

you will have all fields from extract contact Node since its in left node and augment works similar to right join.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So it is not possible to retrieve in single sfdcDigest Transformation? We either have to do update transformation or augment transformation?

Comment: one SFDCDigest node applies to one object. So first you extract what ever fields are required from the Objects and augment them using their relationships.